# jQuery : $(element).on("click",... creates multiple click-events?

Tags: jquery, mobile, onclick

jQuery Mobile:

I'm having this code:

```
$("#header ." + className).on("click",function(event)
    {
    var localValue = localStorage.getItem(selectedInstitut);
    if (localValue === null) {
        localStorage.setItem(selectedInstitut, "favorit");
        console.log("Is NOT favorited. Doing that now")
        $(this).buttonMarkup({theme: 'b'});
        } 
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem(selectedInstitut);
        console.log("Is favorited. Unfavorited now!!")
        $(this).buttonMarkup({theme: 'a'});
        }
    });
```

This works fine one time. But I'm having the same button (different class name though) on several dynamic generated pages.
If the button was clicked on one page and I'm switching to another, it gets into the IF and into the ELSE condition.
If I switch to a 3rd page, it gets into the IF, ELSE and again into the IF statement... And so on for the 4th page.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest binding the event with event delegation from the document, and including it in a global script that won't get executed more than once. What's happening is each time you load a new page, the code is executing again, binding another event.

Comment: `#` selects by `id`, by the way.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I'm kinda new to jQuery.

Comment: Where is the script above located in your DOM relative to the `data-role="page"` element? Is this a signle-page application where you have a single.html with multiple data-role="page" elements?

Comment: yes, I have multiple data-role="page" elements.

I have a seperate .js file with the code. It get's loaded on
$(document).on( 'pageshow', '#detail',function(event){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery Mobile, and the site will put your entire `custom.js` file (or wherever your code is kept) into the cache, the value for `className` is going to be set on the first page, and then **not changed** again because the entire file is added to the cache.

First, make sure all of your `data-role="page"` elements also have a class of `page` to look similar to this:

```
<div data-role="page" class="page">
```

Then, in your JS file, put your code inside this handler:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.page', function(event) {
    // ... your code from above
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. 

I'm already doing that, but I'm using id="page" and not class. Is that a problem?

Comment: If you're doing this already, make sure EACH page has an `id=page' and change `.page` to `#page`. If it STILL does not work, rather than setting this event handler in a single `.js` file, I would put the code on **each** page it needs to be fired on; this will cause the variable for `className` to be "fresh" on each page.

Comment: Can you post all of your code then (since you said you're already doing this)?

Comment: I did on("pageload") that seems to be the problem =)